# add language alias to existing language in vscode (for use in markdown code blocks)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can see how I add languages with aliases to vscode, I also know how to add file associations. However, I'd like to add aliases to existing language names for using them in custom markdown code blocks.

I want to highligh:

````
```run:html
<div></div>
```
````

like

````
```html
<div></div>
```
````

I code my codeblocks with with this special commands for a custom parser to have some extra information.

This is really a luxury issue, but I'd like vscode to highlight the code correctly.

I suspect since vscode does not know "run:html" as a language, it does not hightlight it.
I gueass, since the markdown suppport is native, it uses its internal language registry to render code in markdown. So my idea is to create an alias to my custom type.
I could think of other solution, like having my code commands inside the code, etc. but I find this most readable/maintable.
Maybe a different idea?

Cheers!

JM

Answer (score 1):

It will work if put the language identifier and then your commands (a whitespace is required after the language identifier):

````
```html : run
<div></div>
```
````

Just creating a language alias for `run:html` -> `html` will not work. The markdown extension uses a static mapping of language identifiers to grammars. Instead, you would need to tell markdown about your language using an injection: https://github.com/mjbvz/vscode-fenced-code-block-grammar-injection-example That is complicated. I recommend you change how you are marking your code blocks instead

Comment: Thanks for your input! Marked will choke on this thought :/ I main switch to markdown-it or custom parsing though. Thanks! I might be able to create an alias from the links you posted! Very helpful!